# AppleScript produces no output inside conditional statement

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that tells if application has a specific menubar item. I've found this snippet on the internet, and tried to run, but it doesn't produce any effect. I've spliced into it some debug statements to check the control flow, and it seems not to enter the conditional 'if' at all.

No error message, no output, nothing!

```
on menuItemExists({appName, menuName1, menuItem1})
    display notification "1"
    tell application "System Events"
        display notification "2"
        tell application process appName
            display notification "3"
            if menu item menuItem1 of menu 1 of menu bar item menuName1 of menu bar 1 exists then
                display notification "4"
                return true
            else
                return false
            end if

        end tell
        display notification "5"
    end tell

end menuItemExists

if menuItemExists({"timeEdition", "Extras", "Start Recording"}) then
    display dialog "hoda"
end if
```

Comment: If you want help debugging code, then your question should conform to, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question as presently written is insufficient to debug your failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the AppleScript is functioning as it should, then this leads to one conclusion: at least one of those menu or menu item GUI objects does not exist, and therefore the script has nothing to return.

If that conditional statement passed—and **only** if it passed—then notification 4 would be displayed, and the function `menuItemExists` would return `true`.  If this function returns `true`—and **only** if it returns `true`—then a dialog box would appear displaying the message "hoda".

However, no such dialog appeared, which implies that `menuItemExists` did not return `true`.  If it did not return `true`, then it must have returned `false`.  And if it returned `false`, this means the condition of some menu item’s existence failed, so no notification after number 3 would have been seen.

I believe you were expecting some output even in the event of failure.  However, there is no error in the script, and the only statements that return values are all inside a function handler.  That returns its value (which we’ve now deduced was the boolean value `false`) to the parent script that called it; and it’s only the parent script that would return any value—if it had a value to return—to the output window you were expecting to display a result.

Without having the application you’re using on my computer, it’s not possible for me to determine where in that conditional clause the assertion fails.  My advice is to test each object individually, from `menu bar 1` through to the `menu item` in question, and I’m confident the culprit will emerge.

Answer (score 0):

The **AppleScript** *code* in your OP is only going to return `true` and trigger the `display dialog "hoda"` if and only if **timeEdition** is running and is not actively recording. When it's actively recording the menu shows `Stop Recording`. If **timeEdition** is not running, you can add `tell application "timeEdition" to activate` to the top of the script if you want the *handler* to result in `true` and display "hoda" in a *dialog box* when it's running and not actively recording.

`display notification "5"` will never trigger because of the use of `return` with both `true` and or `false` triggering prior to it.

I installed **timeEdition** and tested the **AppleScript** *code* in your OP and it does return `false` in **Script Editor** if it's not running. If running and not actively recording, it does trigger `display dialog "hoda"`.

So, the **AppleScript** *code* in your OP actually works just as coded, although how it's coded is not of any practical use other then some testing, until its recoded for a real world use case scenario.